# Visual Studio puts red/green squiggles under 'cv2' and 'mediapipe' imports

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense

I am coding in python using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and I have import all the libs I need , but Microsoft Visual Studio  is saying they are not there when they are.

here is a picture of my setup :
[image: Picture of my setup]

the code runs and works, but  both those libs are still highlighted green and The annoying thing about it is, visual Studios  "autocode"  is not working for those libs. So when I do cv2. nothing comes up.

Comment: so the code *runs*? then you're asking how to operate visual studio. that's not a question specific to opencv or mediapipe.

Comment: yes it does run

Comment: I reproduced this issue in Visual studio 2022 17.2.6, you can report this problem to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).